# Drupal 7 search through block content

Tags: 7, views, search

This is my problem:

I used views module to create several blocks of one content type and displayed those blocks in one basic page. My client would like to have that page included in search results when he searches for some word from those blocks.
Seems like Drupal's core search module indexes only content from pages, not content from displayed blocks.
Is there some module that I could use, which would index block's content too?

Comment: where do you want to point the link of the founded content?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will help you, but the way I solved a similar problem was by using Google Search, which indexes the rendered page.

Answer (score 1):

The [Search by page](http://drupal.org/project/search_by_page) module for D7 will search block content, provided it is placed in the same region of the theme as the main page content.  See this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1595200) for details.

If Search by Page does not solve your problem, there is also and abandoned module named [Block Search](http://drupal.org/project/block_search), for D6.  It will not work with D7 of course, but it may be a better starting point for a custom module for D7 than starting from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module [Google Custom Search Engine](http://drupal.org/project/google_cse) that let you embed a Google site search into a Drupal site.  It's still in dev for D7, but seems to work OK.

> Google Custom Search Engine (CSE) is an embedded search engine that can be used to search any set of one or more sites. No Google API key is required.

Read more at [www.google.com/cse/](http://www.google.com/cse/).